# Non-religious word for "blessed"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, connotation

I want to say on social media that I am blessed to have my daughter, but I am not religious and find it awkward when people respond saying that they are sending prayers my way. I appreciate the sentiment, but I'd still like a non-religious word that holds a similar connotation.

Comment: Given current usage, I very much doubt *blessed* is strictly considered *religious* (whatever that might mean). A similar word is *thankful*, which is rarely ever ascribed to any deity in particular in popular usage.

Comment: ..........."happy"?

Comment: I've had multiple experiences of people taking religious connotations. And happy doesn't quite cover it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a religious point of view, being blessed has two parts. The first part is to have been endowed with divine favor. The second part is to be joyful for having received the blessing.

No doubt that as a new father you feel any one of these, from the second part: **overjoyed, jubilant, exultant, elated, gleeful, delighted, or wonderful.** None of these attributes your feeling to any outside influence. With these words, a thesaurus can be used to give you additional ideas.

Comment: I like the breakdown and I believe overjoyed, elated, and delighted work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite is "privileged."

I feel this is the closest in connotation.

Answer (score 5):

*[Extremely] fortunate, [awfully/terribly] lucky.*

Comment: I honestly don't feel like this covers it, but I had thought of these, too.

Answer (score 3):

May be, "Gifted"!

And, like the other answerer has suggested "fortunate" would fit in too.